# c# - drag and drop identify the source listbox

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, listbox, mouseevent

I already have the drag and drop working well. I just need to know is there a way to identify which listbox the dragged item is from?.

Thanks,

Comment: If you posted your code we might be able to help you.

Comment: You cannot find out where it came from.  The simple workaround is to include a reference to the ListBox in the dragged data object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this, i don't think is the best solution but it should work

```
foreach (ListBox _LB in this.Controls.OfType<ListBox>())
        {
            if(_LB.Items.Contains(listBox1.SelectedItem))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(_LB.Name);
            }
        }
```